# Django 1.10.7 ORM annotate query with conditional count over many to many field

Tags: django

Im having a problem using the annnotate function of django to get a conditional count from a many to many field.

I have these 3 models:

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    """
    This model represents an answer to an open question. It just contains
    the answer text and the question it answers.
    """
    answer_description = models.CharField(max_length=1500, blank=True, null=True)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    instrument_submission = models.ForeignKey(InstrumentSubmission)

class MultipleChoiceAnswer(Answer):
    choices = models.ManyToManyField(QuestionChoice)

class QuestionChoice(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    question = models.ForeignKey(MultipleChoiceQuestion)
    explanation_needed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ordinal = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    select_all = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    no_answer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

What I want to do is get all the `MultipleChoiceAnswers` with the total count of the choices field, and an additional count for the correct choices (the ones that have the attribute `is_correct=True`)

As an example, I have one `MultipleChoiceAnswer` that has 2 choices related.
One with `is_correct=True`, the other one with `is_correct=False`.

Then I ran the following test:

```
In [4]: x=MultipleChoiceAnswer.objects.filter(pk=33420)

In [11]: for ans in x:
    ...:     for c in ans.choices.all():
    ...:         print c.is_correct
    ...:         
True
False

In [7]: x=x.annotate(c=Count('choices'),
   ...: 
   ...: correct=Count('choices',filter=Q(is_correct=True)))

In [8]: for a in x:
   ...:     print a.c
   ...:     print a.correct
   ...:     
2
2
```

I would expect to see 2 and then a 1. But the Count is not doing what I expect.

Can anyone help me spot the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure the `filter` argument for annotation is available before django 2.0.
Either way, the filter expression should be something like this: 
`Q(choices__is_correct)`.
My answer is based on these [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `filter` argument was added to aggregates in Django 2, so it will do nothing in Django 1.10. You can however achieve the same thing with a more complex query that uses [conditional expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/conditional-expressions/):

```
from django.db.models import Case, Count, IntegerField, When

ans.annotate(correct=Sum(
    Case(
        When(choices__is_correct=True, then=1),
        default=0,
        output_field=IntegerField(),
    )
))
```

This basically adds up all the choices which are correct and returns a count of them for each answer.

Comment: (Side note: Django 1.10 is end of life. You should consider upgrading.)